# Is my father allowed not to distribute his property to his daughters while alive?

Tags: muslim-practices, parents, inheritance

My father has land . He has 4 daughters and no sons . He does not divide the land and give to daughters . He doesn't like to give .

He says, take the land after I died.

**What's the Islamic ruling on this ? Is he allowed to do so or is he doing wrong ?**

Comment: He is not obliged to distribute his property during his lifetime. Inheritance is executed after death. An exception being the scenario where the person feels that some of his/her inheritors may be deprived of their rightful share. In such a scenario a will may be created or the property be distributed as per how it should have been after death. But if a child is born after the will or distribution takes place, the property will need to redivided. There is some debate on this issue among the Ulema.

Comment: "He has 4 daughters and no sons" ... what about yourself?

Answer (score 1):

It be his personal property, he not be required to give any of his property to anyone. He is only required to spend on his daughter's expenses if they are unmarried. It is only after his death that it will be divided in inheritance. 
Actually what he is doing is smart as children can be ungrateful and cruel, they will take the land and abandon the father.

Answer (score 0):

Is my father allowed not to divide his property among his daughters while he is alive?
Inheritance is after the death of a person and no one from relatives or children has the right to claim inheritance during life.

Ref:https://article.tebyan.net/271692/%